# What is " Windows Installer database schema"?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

Quote

> Use a **Windows Installer database schema** of 200 or higher. Specify that
> version 2.0 is the minimum version of the installer required to
> install the package by setting the Page Count Summary property to the
> integer 200. Earlier Windows Installer versions reject attempts to
> install 64-bit packages. For 64-bit packages on the Arm64 platform,
> the Windows Installer database schema must be 500 or higher.

What is " Windows Installer database schema"? in context of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/using-64-bit-windows-installer-packages

What is the meaning of `200`, `500`, `501`?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer database schema is minimum Windows Installer version that is required by your installation package. For a windows installer 2.0, schema value is 200. For windows installer 5.0, schema value should be 500.

If user's system has Windows installer version earlier than the specified in installer, it will display the error and exits.

Comment: I am totally new comer with term "database schema". Please explain for me, and give more information about this term in a easy way for new comer.

Comment: Windows installer is not something that would be easily explained in a Stack Overflow comment. I would suggest some googling and then come back with further more detailed questions. There is a wiki page for Windows installer but there are a lot of good responses on [this post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709452/what-does-windows-installer-itself-actually-do-and-why-do-i-never-see-an-msi-mad). The installer file is generally an MSI file type and that is your database. You can view the database with a tool called Orca.

Answer (score 0):

You can see database schema at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/database-tables